# Tkinter, ejecutar una funcion al dar enter en un Entry sin un boton

Tags: python, tkinter

soy nuevo en tkinter.

Quiero escribir un numero de serie en un Entry Widget y despues dar enter y que se ejecute una funcion, por ejemplo mostrar una venta emergente. Todo esto sin la necesidad de tener un boton que lea el texto en el entry y ejecute un comando.

Como interfaz quiero dejar algo asi de sencilo:

```
import tkinter as tk
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("FT Files")
window.geometry("500x300")

texto=tk.Label(window,text="Introduce un numero de serie:")
texto.pack()
#NumSerie=StringVar()
serialEntry=tk.Entry(window)
serialEntry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitar usar la función `bind` en tu `entry` y asignarle a la tecla `enter` una función

```
import tkinter as tk
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("FT Files")
window.geometry("500x300")

texto=tk.Label(window,text="Introduce un numero de serie:")
texto.pack()
#NumSerie=StringVar()
serialEntry=tk.Entry(window)
serialEntry.pack()

def newWindow(event):
    print("the new window is open")
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(window)

    new_label = tk.Label(new_window)
    new_label.config(text="El codigo de serie es: " + serialEntry.get())
    new_label.place(x=30,y=30)

    window.iconify()

serialEntry.bind("<Return>", newWindow)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Justo es lo que queria hacer, gracias!